# Laravel Eloquent query for daily, weekly and overall sales

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am developing a Laravel application for daily, weekly and overall sales with this model class.

**Model**

```php
class Sales extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sales';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'store',
        'amount',
        'created_at'
    ];
}
```

I want to display daily, weekly and overall sales. This should be based on and grouped by store. I have written this code below in the controller, but don't know how to complete it.

**Controller**

```php
public function sales()
{
    $billings = DB::table("sales")
        ->select("sales.store", DB::raw("SUM(sales.amount) as total_amount"))
        ->groupBy("sales.store")
        ->orderByRaw('sales.store ASC');

    return view('report.sales');
}
```

The date is `created_at` and it is DateTime. How do I make my code to include daily, weekly and overall sales? I want to achieve something like the following.

[image: sales_report]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Sum with a Case condition could help. Not tested but roughly how i would draw it up check if it gets you any further.

```
$billings = DB::table("sales")
    ->select(
        "sales.store",
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN amount ELSE 0 END) weekly_sales",
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN amount ELSE 0 END) monthly_sales",
        DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN amount ELSE 0 END) yearly_sales",
        DB::raw("SUM(amount) total_sales")
    )
    ->groupBy("sales.store")
    ->orderByRaw('sales.store ASC');
```

Comment: Then how about the overall sales?

Comment: Glad it worked :) any changes to the code, or was it all good?

Comment: It was all good. I only added         DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN amount ELSE 0 END) daily_sales",         for daily sales